# Flutter : dynamic link always go to play store don't open app on device

Tags: flutter, firebase-dynamic-links, android-deep-link

I created a deep link on firebase

then added this code inside main activity

```
 <!-- Deep linking -->
            <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="myapp.page.link"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

the link always goes to the store and doesn't open the app
I tried debug mode
and created a release
but the still the same result

Comment: is your app published to play store?

Comment: provide manifest file

Comment: It worked good when I sent the link through social media apps, but it's not working when I added it from the mobile browser